# Run batch file via protocol on local network

Tags: javascript, batch-file, network-programming, protocols

I have a couple of tests written in javascript that are run locally. I need to be able to restore my database before running them, so I figured I would allow testers to select which backup they want to restore in their tests. They would call a function that would run a `.bat` which would restore a database, and then they could continue executing tests.

I know that I cannot run files directly from javascript, but if I would setup a server and run this `.bat` via some protocol then I would be able to run the file. I just don't know which protocol would be suitable for this. I just need something that is easy to setup, because I just need to run 1 `.bat`.

I was thinking about SSH, but I don't know if this is suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend a loton the environment in which are you running your tests (i.e. in browser you are pretty much limited to what a normal web page would be capable of, in nodejs you have more options, etc).

Assuming that you use the browser as your environment, then you can implement a backend server that restores a particular backup if you GET certain url. A bit more challenging, but, perhaps, more correct would be to use websockets to pass commands to the server.

Having said that, SSH is the correct choice if you can use it from your test framework. It provides security and flexibility.

Comment: I used ssh2 to create server/client on node.js. I can run bat files via ssh. Works pretty good :)